# XLSX file reading error

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, apache-camel

I am trying to read xlsx file to get data form file 
but my code generate en eroor like this

apache poi is not working or help to read xlsx file
any can tell what i need to do solve this error
or other way to read xlsx file in java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:161)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:223)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
    at ExampleEventUserModel.processOneSheet(ExampleEventUserModel.java:18)
    at ExampleEventUserModel.main(ExampleEventUserModel.java:115)
```

Comment: You should post a code snippet as well.

Comment: Without the code it's hard to be sure, but my hunch is that you're doing `open, close, read` which isn't allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read xlsx file. We must use

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue and **fixed** it by giving the **absolute path** instead of just file name.

Instead of giving

OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);

You can give

OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(absolutePath + "/"  + filename);

Comment: I was having this issue as well, and this fixed it!

Comment: how about code running on different machines?
Would it be a good practice to use absolute path.